# Are there any map/undirected-graph recognition systems in existence?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

If there is a sketch (on paper) of a graph, or DAG or even a binarized image of a street-map -- is there any optical recognition system that can analyse the map or graph and then compute the shortest path, etc?

Was thinking of a meaningful project and this came to mind. However can't figure out what keywords to search Google for previous or related work. Is there any specific name for such work in this field? (e.g. "text in natural scenes" is generally used when we're talking about detecting text from outdoor photos as opposed to scanned pages... that way)

**EDIT:** Please note I'm not asking for a solution to the problem, but already existing stuff, apps, projects or published papers etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For undirected graphs (starting from a map) you may start by doing something like:

```
1) Apply a Thinning
2) Find the skeleton
3) Find the BranchPoints and Endpoints (use them as vertices)
4) Add edges where the BranchPoints and EndPoints are 8-connected
5) Use your favorite shortest path finder
```

Let's apply it to a street map:

[image]

Comment: thanks but i wasn't searching for an algo or solution to the problem - i've already done that using corner-detectors for finding the vertices. Wanted **related work** as in papers, apps etc. that are already in existence.

Comment: @AruniRC your question was "is there any optical recognition system that can analyse the map or graph and then compute the shortest path". Belisarius' answer shows that there is at least one such system, namely Mathematica. Seems like a correct answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

These four blog posts deal with image processing mazes and path finding.

http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/11/03/amazeing-image-processing-in-mathematica/
http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/07/navigating-the-blenheim-maze/
http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/12/21/the-battle-of-the-marlborough-maze-at-blenheim-palace-continues/
http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/02/01/retreat-from-blenheim/

Answer (score 1):

I think the term you are looking for is "Graphics Recognition".  A Google search with this term provides a lot of related work to look at.

You can find many related papers from proceedings of the International Workshop on Graphics RECognition or GREC.  The proceedings aren't online, but if you are a student, your university may have them available for you.